# error while updating property coordinate' of a view managed by airmap marker null latitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I Keep getting this error when I run my `react` native app and try to set the location. I'm building an uber clone app, but whenever I set the origin, destination and try to get to the next screen it brings up the error:

```
error while updating property coordinate' of a view managed by airmap marker null latitude
```

[Screenshot of the error in android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIhsx.png)

CODE BELOW

```
import React from "react";
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'API_KEY_HERE'; 
const RouteMap = ({ origin, destination }) => {

  const originLoc = {
    latitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lng,
  };

  const destinationLoc = {
    latitude: destination.details.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: destination.details.geometry.location.lng,
  };

  return (
    <MapView
      style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 28.450627,
        longitude: -16.263045,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0222,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}>
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={originLoc}
        destination={destinationLoc}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={5}
        strokeColor="black"
      />
      <Marker
        coordinate={origin}
        title={'Origin'}
      />
      <Marker
        coordinate={destination}
        title={"Destination"}
      />
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default RouteMap;
```

Comment: I removed the API key you provided in the sample code. Please don't share your API key in public sites like Stack Overflow in the future. As for your issue, have you checked the value passed by your origin and destination? Are those values not null and not string? As the error message shows, it seems that the value you are passing is null.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Mustapha Ahmed Yusuf** Welcome on **SOF**.The issue you are facing came when you are giving null `lat & long` to region.You have to console the `lat & long`.
Before doing this

```
 const originLoc = {
    latitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lng,
  };
```

you have to `console.log()` `origin.details.geometry.location.lat` & `origin.details.geometry.location.lng` in order to check either they are **null** or not.if null then you have to figure it out.if it is **string** make sure convert it into **floating** values using `parseFloat(latitude)` && `parseFloat(longitude)`.I hope you will be able to find the issue